# Web Api - response in JSON format - swagger documentation

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, web, swagger

I want create ASP.NET WEB API with swagger documentation, but I have strange problem. When I set api format using my own implemenation of JSON formatter, swagger documenation is disabled. In console I can see that JavaScript Exception is throwing.

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

[image]
[image]

> {"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"REST","description":null,"termsOfService":null,"contact":null,"license":null,"vendorExtensions":{}},"host":"localhost:58144","basePath":null,"schemes":["http"],"consumes":null,"produces":null,"paths":{"/api/Users":{"$ref":null,"get":{"tags":["Users"],"summary":null,"description":null,"externalDocs":null,"operationId":"Users_GetUsers","consumes":[],"produces":["application/json","text/json","application/xml","text/xml"],"parameters":null,"responses":{"200":{"description":"OK","schema":{"$ref":null,"format":null,"title":null,"description":null,"default":null,"multipleOf":null,"maximum":null,"exclusiveMaximum":null,"minimum":null,"exclusiveMinimum":null,"maxLength":null,"minLength":null,"pattern":null,"maxItems":null,"minItems":null,"uniqueItems":null,"maxProperties":null,"minProperties":null,"required":null,"enum":null,"type":"array","items":

Comment: What does `http://localhost:58144/swagger/docs/v1` return? An error maybe?

Comment: I have added part of http://localhost:58144/swagger/docs/v1 to question above